# Unable to remove punctuation by translate or strip

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove punctuation and below is the codeimport string

```
strtext = "Professor Michael S. Hart is @ the originator of the Project Gutenberg-tm, concept // of a library of electronic works that could be freely shared with anyone.  For thirty years, he produced and distributed Project Gutenberg-tm eBooks with only a loose network of volunteer support."
print(strtext.strip(string.punctuation))
```

When I use `print(strtext.translate(None, string.punctuation))`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(strtext.translate(None, string.punctuation))
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

And when I use `print(strtext.translate(string.punctuation))` punctuation is not removed.

What could be the problem here?

And yes, I did a search and came upon couple of questions on stackoverflow but did not solve my problem.

Comment: you're probably using python3

Comment: Yes, I am using python3, @rrw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works (in Python3):

```
print(strtext.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)))
```

About your attempts:

`strtext.strip(string.punctuation)` will try to remove each character from `string.punctuation` (`'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'`) from the beginning and end of`strtext`. It will not remove characters inside the string.

`strtext.translate(None, string.punctuation)`: `translate()`  needs a single dict as argument, which you build using maketrans() like above.

Comment: Yes it does.

Is there a simpler way to do like just throw in the string.punctuation and voila! :)

Answer (score 1):

<s>import string</s>

```
string.translate(strtext, None, string.punctuation)
```

OR

```
strtext.translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

---

> `string.translate(s, table[, deletechars])`
>
> If table is None, then only the character deletion step is performed.

[**string.translate doc**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate)

---

**Note** Valid only on python2

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(string.translate(strtext, None, string.punctuation))
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'translate'

For - strtext.translate(None, string.punctuation) - The error message is in the Q

Comment: my string is strtext

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print (strtext.translate(strtext, None, string.punctuation))
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

Comment: That's for Python 2. In Python3 you need to create a translation dict and pass it as single arg to `translate` like in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You're using python3 <s>(most probably)</s>.

try:

```
trans_table = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, string.punctuation), None)
print(strtext.translate(trans_table))
```